# How do I fix my navigation bar which appears to be shifted in nexus devices?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-actionbar

I have a navigation bar at the top of my app. It look fine if galaxy/htc devices as follows:
[image]
However, in nexus devices it seems to shift a little as follows, not sure why:

[image]
Here is my code for the same : (actionbar.xml) :

```
   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:foo="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.justin.abc"
        android:id="@+id/title_information_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#27272b"
        android:fillViewport="true" >

        <com.justin.abc.utils.FontTextView
            android:id="@+id/actionbar_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/actionbar_title_height"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/actionbar_title_topmargin"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/common_left_padding"
            android:text="@string/title_about"
            foo:customFont="proxima-nova-regular-Regular.ttf"


            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="@dimen/actionbar_title" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_done"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/done_button_height"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/done_button_topmargin"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/done_button_leftmargin"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/done_button_rightmargin"
            android:background="@drawable/done_cancel_button"
            android:text="@string/menu_done"
            android:textColor="@drawable/done_button_text"
            android:textSize="@dimen/button_text" />


        <View
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/actionbar_view_margintop"
            android:background="@color/black"
            android:visibility="visible" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Any clues how I can fix the same so it works well in all devices? Thanks!

This is the associated theme:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock"></style>

<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar" parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock.NoActionBar"></style>

<style name="AppBaseTheme.NoActionBar" parent="AppTheme.NoActionBar"></style>

<!-- Although this is doing exactly what AppBaseTheme is doing,
    it fixes the initialization display of the icon being truncated -->
 <style name="ABTheme"  parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="homeAsUpIndicator">@null</item>
    <item name="selectableItemBackground">@drawable/btn_selector_home_icon</item>
</style>

<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="homeAsUpIndicator">@null</item>
    <item name="selectableItemBackground">@drawable/btn_selector_home_icon</item>
    <item name="android:listViewStyle">@style/ListViewAppTheme</item>

    <item name="android:listViewWhiteStyle">@style/ListViewAppTheme.White</item>

    <item name="android:spinnerItemStyle">@style/SpinnerItemAppTheme</item>
</style>

<style name="ListViewAppTheme" parent="android:Widget.ListView">
    <item name="android:listSelector">@drawable/list_selector_holo_light</item>
</style>

<style name="ListViewAppTheme.White" parent="android:Widget.ListView.White">
    <item name="android:listSelector">@drawable/list_selector_holo_light</item>
</style>

<style name="SpinnerItemAppTheme" parent="android:TextAppearance.Widget.TextView.SpinnerItem">
    <item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>
</style>
<style name="abc.TextView" parent="android:Widget.Holo.TextView"></style>

<style name="T1UserContactCountry">
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#cccccc</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/title</item>
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">@dimen/common_left_padding</item>
    <item name="android:layout_gravity">left</item>
</style>
<style name="T1UserContactPhone">
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/abs__holo_blue_light</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/title</item>
    <item name="android:onClick">onPhoneNumberClicked</item>
    <item name="android:paddingRight">@dimen/common_right_padding</item>
    <item name="android:layout_gravity">right</item>
    <item name="android:clickable">true</item>
</style>
<style name="T1TableRowSeparator">
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:paddingTop">10dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingBottom">10dp</item>
</style>
<style name="T1ViewSeparator">
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">2dp</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/header_grey</item>
    <item name="android:layout_span">2</item>
</style>

<style name="abc.TextView.ListsTextView">
    <item name="android:ellipsize">end</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">right</item>
    <item name="android:singleLine">true</item>
    <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>

<style name="abc.TextView.ListsTextView.Header">
    <item name="android:paddingTop">2dp</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">15sp</item>
    <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
<style name="CustomTheme">
   <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/custom_theme_color</item>
<item name="android:colorBackground">@color/custom_theme_color</item>
</style>
<style name="abc.TextView.ListsTextView.Value">
    <item name="android:textSize">15sp</item>
    <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>

<style name="abc.TextView.NavigationItem">
    <item name="android:clickable">true</item>
    <item name="android:padding">3dp</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/black</item>
</style>

<style name="search_autosuggest_header" parent="android:Widget.Holo.TextView">
    <item name="android:paddingBottom">5dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">3dp</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/search_autosuggest_header_text</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/background_search_auto_suggest_header</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
</style>

<style name="abc.TextView.Preferences">
    <item name="android:padding">8dp</item>
</style>

<style name="abc.TextView.Preferences.Title">
    <item name="android:background">@color/black</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/background_preferences_item</item>
</style>

<style name="abc.TextView.Preferences.Item">
    <item name="android:background">@color/background_preferences_item</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/background_preferences_title</item>
</style>

<style name="abc.TextView.Preferences.Item.clickable">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/background_preferences_layout_selector</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/background_preferences_title</item>
</style>

<style name="abc.Button.Toggle" parent="android:Widget.Holo.Button.Toggle">
    <item name="android:button">@null</item>
    <item name="android:textOff"></item>
    <item name="android:textOn"></item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/toggle_selector_abc</item>
</style>

<style name="LoginEditText" parent="@android:style/Widget.EditText">
    <item name="@android:textColor">@color/textbox_hint</item>
    <item name="@android:textSize">16sp</item>
    <item name="@android:maxLines">1</item>
    <item name="@android:fontFamily">Roboto-Regular</item>
</style>

 <style name="MenuDialogAnimation">
     <item name="android:windowEnterAnimation">@anim/grow_from_topright_to_bottomleft</item>
     <item name="android:windowExitAnimation">@anim/shrink_from_bottomleft_to_topright</item>
 </style>

 <style name="MenuDialogAnimationLeft">
     <item name="android:windowEnterAnimation">@anim/grow_from_topleft_to_bottomright</item>
     <item name="android:windowExitAnimation">@anim/shrink_from_bottomright_to_topleft</item>
 </style>

 <style name="BriefcaseMenuDialogAnimation">
     <item name="android:windowEnterAnimation">@android:anim/fade_in</item>
     <item name="android:windowExitAnimation">@android:anim/fade_out</item>
 </style>
 <style name="ButtonText">
    <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#ffffff</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
    <item name="android:layout_margin">3dp</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">30dp</item>
    <item name="android:shadowColor">#000000</item>
    <item name="android:shadowDx">1</item>
    <item name="android:shadowDy">1</item>
    <item name="android:shadowRadius">2</item>
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">15dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingRight">15dp</item>
</style>
<style name="Divider">
     <item name="android:divider">@drawable/divider</item>
     <item name="android:dividerHeight">1px</item>

</style>

<style name="related_buttons" parent="android:Widget.Holo.TextView">
    <item name="android:clickable">true</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center_vertical|left</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginBottom">3dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginTop">3dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">12dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingRight">12dp</item>
    <item name="android:visibility">gone</item>
    <item name="android:drawableRight">@drawable/arrow_chevron_selector</item>
</style>
```

In my manifest I am referencing it as follows:

```
 <application
        android:name=".abcApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/abc_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_long_name"
        android:theme="@style/ABTheme" android:debuggable="false">
```

Here's my java code:

```
public void manageActionBar() {
        final ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.actionbar_no_button);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
        final TextView titleView = (TextView) actionBar.getCustomView().findViewById(R.id.actionbar_title);
        titleView.setText(R.string.personal);
    }
```

Comment: Is there a particular reason you are not using the standard Android action bar?

Comment: I wanted to customize the look based on my project req's

Comment: In the xml i see three view, a label, a button and a view...but in the screenshot is not visible this view, what is it?

Comment: the label is the about text, button is the done button on the right, and the view in a bottom black 2dp border line which isnt that visible in the screenshot

Comment: I sense a pattern missing here, can you tell me where is manageactiobar() being called?

Comment: Sure, it's being called in my baseactivity in oncreate method

Answer (score 2):

The reason this is not working is because this is not the way you customize the [Action Bar](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html), I suggest reading about how to customize the `Action Bar` [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Style).

What you want to do basically is define a [theme](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html) for your application, as you stated in the comments you want to change the look based on your project requirements.

Here is the example from the article I've linked above:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <!-- the theme applied to the application or activity -->
    <style name="CustomActionBarTheme"
           parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarTabTextStyle">@style/TabTextStyle</item>
        <item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">@color/actionbar_text</item>

        <!-- Support library compatibility -->
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
        <item name="actionBarTabTextStyle">@style/TabTextStyle</item>
        <item name="actionMenuTextColor">@color/actionbar_text</item>
    </style>

    <!-- general styles for the action bar -->
    <style name="MyActionBar"
           parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/TitleTextStyle</item>
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/actionbar_background</item>
        <item name="android:backgroundStacked">@drawable/actionbar_background</item>
        <item name="android:backgroundSplit">@drawable/actionbar_background</item>

        <!-- Support library compatibility -->
        <item name="titleTextStyle">@style/TitleTextStyle</item>
        <item name="background">@drawable/actionbar_background</item>
        <item name="backgroundStacked">@drawable/actionbar_background</item>
        <item name="backgroundSplit">@drawable/actionbar_background</item>
    </style>

    <!-- action bar title text -->
    <style name="TitleTextStyle"
           parent="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/actionbar_text</item>
    </style>

    <!-- action bar tab text -->
    <style name="TabTextStyle"
           parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar.TabText">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/actionbar_text</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

After doing that, you can customize the look of your `Action Bar` to look just the way you want it to (Make sure you set the colors the right way).

Comment: So do I need to change my entire actionbar code to make it work or is there an easier way around?

Comment: The link I added have pretty much everything you need to get exactly what you want. If by ActionBar code you mean the XML you posted, then yes, you'll need to change it.
You can see here it's pretty easy: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html

https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/adding-buttons.html

Comment: Didn't get around it yet, but will give it a shot today, was trying to figure out a fix with the existing code.

Comment: Currently using Actionbar sherlock, is there a way I can modify that to work for all devices?

Comment: I updated my question with the theme I am using and the android manifest xml application theme call. Can you please let me know how I can modify the same? Thanks!

Comment: Hey @JusticeBauer, I think it will be best to use the AppCompat lib instead of ActionBarSherlock, but ABS is OK too. Please take into consideration that this doesn't actually help you much with theming and you will still need to write your style XML. You can see here: http://actionbarsherlock.com/theming.html

Comment: Also please read this: http://android-developers.blogspot.co.il/2011/04/customizing-action-bar.html
it's a good place to start, and since you don't require too much customizing, it will be rather quick.

Comment: On debugging I found out in certain nexus devices , this line : getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false); is causing an issue ,even with false it creates a gap, is there a way to fix this, or hide this completely?

Comment: The other dude posted the solution, but thanks for the attempting the answer, +10 for the effort , cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I'm having some problem with the ActionBar as well.  And the problems only appears on Nexus 7 (I don't have other Nexus).  I placed my custom view inside the action bar, to completely cover it up (because it can't be configure to the way I want).

```
LayoutParams layout = new LayoutParams( LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT );
LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService( Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE );
View v = inflator.inflate( R.layout.my_actionbar_layout, null );
getActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled( true );
getActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled( false );
getActionBar().setCustomView( v, layout );
```

However, there is a gap on the left size and the view goes too far over the right edge of screen.

The solution, however, is very simple:

```
getActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
```

Hope this help you (and others).

Credits:
I found the answer from this page:
http://answer.techwikihow.com/1352928/actionbar-customview-extra-padding-cannot-removed.html